# c++ make the base class use overridden methods in the child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to override a method of the base class used by another method in the base class; however, when the derived class invokes the using-method of the base class, the derived used-method is never executed, but instead the base class's used-method is called. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    void printLeft() { cout << this->getLeft(); }
    int getLeft() { return 0; }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}
    int getLeft() { return 1; }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Derived d = Derived();
    d.printLeft();
}
```

Running `main()` prints `0`, indicating `Base`'s `getLeft()` method was used rather than the derived object's method.

How can I change this code so `Derived::getLeft()` is called **when called from an instance of Derived**?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time. This project is due tomorrow. Thank you, however, for your helpful suggestion.

Comment: For the downvoter(s), is there something particularly wrong with the question? Should I clarify something? I tried researching, but as I don't know the terminology for the phenomenon I'm trying to describe, I wasn't able to find any pertinent results.

Comment: I downvoted this question, but I didn't do that until you told me that you were unwilling to read a book to learn C++.

Comment: Gotcha. I was concerned the downvote may have been in some way relevant. Glad to know it was only personal. Thank you for your honesty.

Comment: [It's not personal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128589/142865).  You can't learn C++ well by reading an online tutorial.  You don't do your co-workers, your employers, your teachers or yourself any good by trying to take shortcuts and get spoon-feeding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11283/discussion-between-weberc2-and-john-dibling)

Comment: I accepted the invitation to chat, but weberc2 closed the chat before I had a chance to elaborate.  Therefore, I will try to elaborate here.

Comment: This question is noise.  A fundamental, beginner C++ question that was posted in an attempt to ask the internet instead of taking the time to sit down and really learn C++.  I see no attempt by the poster to do their own research, which was confirmed when the poster refused my original suggestion.  I did not d/v out of retailiation, as suggested by OP, but because this question adds to the noise on SO, which makes it a bad question.

Comment: Sorry, I honestly didn't mean to close the chat, nor did I realize I did. I'll try to open it back up again. Sincere apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to make `getLeft` virtual:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    void printLeft() { cout << this->getLeft(); }
    virtual int getLeft() { return 0; }
};
```

By default in C++ , member functions are not virtual. That is, you can't override them in a subclass.

Comment: Well, you *can* override them, it's just that the overriding will not have any effect when called through a base class pointer or reference.

Answer (score 1):

For non-virtual functions, the static type of the object is used to determine which class's method is called.

In your case, you are calling `getLeft()` from `Base::printLeft()`. The type of `this` is `Base*`, so the function called will be `Base::getLeft()`.

The way around this is to use the `virtual` keyword.  In that case, the virtual function table will be used to determine which version of `getLeft()` to call, in this case `Derived.`

You can trigger this behavior by prepending `virtual` to the declarations of `printLeft` in both `Base` and `Derived`.